# Не могу понять где взять модуль с протобафами

Tags: python, python-3.x, steam, google-protobuf

На [этой](https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/steam.client.gc.html) странице документации по модулю steam написано "The above code assumes that we have a myDotaModule that contains the appropriate protobufs needed to (de)serialize message for communication with GC."
Но где мне взять этот модуль

Comment: Ввожу в гугл `protobuf python`, немного вниз проматываю и вижу ссылку https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf :) Есть еще страница на pypi https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/

Comment: Думаю, эта библиотека подразумевает, что Вы уже знаете, что такое gRPС и у Вас уже есть нужные `.proto` файлы и сгенерированный из них Python-код. Пятиминутное гугление выводит на https://github.com/ValvePython/csgo/tree/master/csgo/protobufs, но, насколько я помню, код, генерируемый из `.proto`, является платформозависимым и не самой лучшей идеей является брать уже готовый.